# Shall I remove broken or partly dead leaves of a Kalanchoe?

Tags: succulents, flowering, tropical, fleshy-leaves

I have two [Kalanchoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe).

The first one of them did not bloom, and some leaves I think are starting to die. Is there anything I can do to help it bloom? Shall I remove the dying leaves?

[image]

The second one has broken leaves, but has more flowers. Shall I only remove the broken leaves?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kalanchoe is water and light sensitive. Water only after the root ball has mostly dried out, and in order to produce flowers they need to see short days in winter after which they will produce flowers. The period of short days might be between 9 and 13 weeks (see reference below for more details).

So for your two problems: use a sharp tool to nip off the unsightly dead tissues - it is not necessary to clip the entire leaf, just the dead part. Water sparingly and only after the root has dried down. The naturally smooth and shiny leaves will protect against fungus spores, so just keep water away from the leaves and stalks. One way to tell if the plant needs water is to feel the weight of the pot and plant; light weight means it could be time to water. Lift the pot and tap the side of the pot lightly with a stick. If it makes a dull sound then the root is likely damp enough; a hollow sound means there is lots of air in the pot and water could be required. The plant that did not flower might not have received the required length of darkness in winter.

A comprehensive source of information about growing Kalanchoe is http://www.ag.auburn.edu/landscape/Kalanchoe.htm